# Javascript pad out array of dicts and sort to align dictionary keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Sorry about confusing title. No idea how to phrase it shortly or easily
I have a data array which looks like this;

```
[
  [
    {key:1, header:"a", value"text1"},
    {key:2, header:"b", value"text2"},
    {key:2, header:"c", value"text2"},
    {key:3, header:"d", value"text3"},
  ],
  [
    {key:1, header:"a", value"text4"},
    {value:""},
    {key:3, header:"d", value"text5"},
  ]
]
```

That I need to transform into this;

```
[
  [
    {key:1, header:"a", value"text1"},
    {key:2, header:"b", value"text2"},
    {key:2, header:"c", value"text2"},
    {key:3, header:"d", value"text3"},
  ],
  [
    {key:1, header:"a", value"text4"},
    {value:""},
    {value:""},
    {key:3, header:"d", value"text5"}
  ]
]
```

So it will fill the dimensions of a table component a site I'm working on and retain the alignment of the **keys**.
Spent the better part of two evenings on this problem now with no luck.
The easiest way to describe the goal is that the array needs to be manipulated and padded out with placeholders so the `'key'` properties are always aligned "along the j axis" as in `array[i][j]` and the `array[i].length` is the same for every row.
In some cases the original data will have empty placeholder values like the `{value:""},` field in the first array above.
The array can have anywhere from 1 to 10 rows and each rows can sometimes contain up to 20 dict fields with the empty placeholders at semi-random locations.

Comment: is only the first one complete?

Comment: In a case where there are several rows, I think there **could** be several rows lacking, I believe the top one will always be complete though.

Comment: it's a bit tricky because of the non unique `key` values ...